# HTTP request in For loop, Low Memory and Crashed

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-request

I need to send a large amount of HTTP request in a for loop, and once I finish a task, I need to update progress on main thread.

```
 float __block progress = 0.0f;
 float __block tempValue = 0.0f;

dispatch_queue_t operationQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Operation Data", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);

for (int uploadCount = 0; uploadCount < mutableArray.count; uploadCount++) {

    dispatch_barrier_async(operationQueue, ^{
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        DDLogInfo(@"add Task.");
        [MPRestAPI copyMediaToAlbum:mutableArray[uploadCount] targetAlbum:albumName success:^(BOOL bSuccess){
            if (bSuccess) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    progress = (float)(uploadCount+1)/(float)mutableArray.count;
                    if(uploadCount+1 == mutableArray.count){
                        progressHUD.progress = 1.0;
                        [progressHUD hide:YES];
                        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
                    }else if(progress > tempValue) {
                        progressHUD.progress = progress;
                        tempValue = progress + 0.01;
                    }
                });
            }
        }failure:^(NSError* error){
            if(uploadCount == mutableArray.count -1){
                [progressHUD hide:YES];
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
            }
        }];
    });

    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
}
```

Then there comes low memory, and it crashed. and `mutableArray.count` can be 5000,so I wonder what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: You can subdivide it to 50 request at a time